# Content Encoding Error

Tags: cache

I just installed wordpress through A2Hosting and I added blocksy as a theme. So it is a brand new site. I got the Content Encoding Error when trying to access my site and I managed to solve it by clearing site cache from the admin page. However, it happens too often, I think every two hours or so, even when I don't do any modifications from the page. I work with firefox. When I get the error, I can access normally from other browsers like chrome, so is either firefox or something with the admin session that messes up the website.